# Method 'setProviders' is marked deprecated in Spring Security 3.2.7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.7 and I got this warning in my spring configuration

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Method 'setProviders' is marked deprecated

security-config.xml:

```
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login**" 
                             default-target-url="/dashboard**" 
                             authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?failed=true"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.xhtml"/>


    </security:http>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.tds.erp.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl"
        autowire="default" />

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.tds.erp.services.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" ></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>

            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
<!--                <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/> -->
            </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following for the authentication manager

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thank you, it's working fine and the warning has been removed !